# Get SBC micro browser content in html website

Tags: javascript, java, windows, applet

When I want to open a link from the [SBC micro browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saiaburgess.microbrowser&hl=nl&gl=US) in a "normal" browser I get the following error:

> The visualization runtime could not be started. The browser does not
> support Java, the Java plug-in is not installed or the Applet could
> not be loaded.

Is there a way to open this link without installing any applications (as java). I want my website to be available for any browser (safari, chrome, ...). I was thinking about writing some code in JavaScript and/or PHP. Can someone help me?

The links looks like this: `https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/4CLSLx_kBSeRt6X5b6tXwXoTLcmOQNIFq-oml6-eE_sMcZexPkJE9JAhp4UEl5pqJew=w1536-h754-rw`

The content of the "webpage" looks like this : `https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/cAZsalgjRwG5PEjFaN_GGB0l3eRvJyUFSek3Uply-ja2Ad_83OtJ5qnzz3G2bqTZNDg=w1536-h754-rw`

It's a dashboard with changing values that represent Measurements.

The body of the html page looks like this

```
<body>
  <applet archive="IMasterSaia5_15_03.jar" code="IMasterSaia5_15_03.class" width="1024" height="768" class="teqruntime">
    <param name="java_arguments" value="-Xms256m -Xmx512m">
    <param name="AppletName" value="Webpanel Central">

    ...(a lot more <param> )
    
  </applet>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the link (and sure, redact any parts of it that can be redacted)? Because if it's `https://...` then it works in every browser, and if it's not, then it's not a regular URL and normal web browsers are not designed to load them.

Comment: it's a http://... link. If regular web browsers are not designed to load them. How am I abel to do let them perform that?

Comment: if it's plain http, that's an insecure link, but most browsers will still load it (with warnings in their security notification area). However, So: is it an http link to a web page (i.e. written in HTML with CSS/JS as additional content)? Because it sounds like it's an http link to "not actually web page".

Comment: It isn't an actual web page. I think it's (more like) a Java-applet. (I've added some links to my question. I didn't have enough reputation to add an image.)

Comment: You don't need rep to add an image, but an image wouldn't have made sense here anyway: that link goes to a webpage with an image on it, so is that _the actualy http link_ that you get from the micro browser? Or is that a link you made to show off "what it looks like in the micro browser", because the former is an important detail to your question, whereas the latter is not useful because it's not about what things look like, but whether the http:// link points to real web content on a normal domain, or to some kind of "this isn't actually HTML at all" at a device-only network location.

Comment: In the new added link you can see what the content looks like.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I was asking: you are trying to get a URL from a browser, to another browser: what is _that URL_, not "can you show a picture of what it looks like". Also, have you contacted SBC Micro Browser's support? (they have an email address listed on their play store entry, so that would be a place to also ask, even if you've posted to SO. The most qualified people to help here, is them)

Comment: My excuses for the late answer. I will send them sommeting. Thanks for the assistance